# Help understanding one of Euler's theorem in Number Theory

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, induction

I am looking at two Euler's theorems in my textbook which are the following:

**If $p$ is prime and $a$ is any whole number, then $(a+1)^p - (a^p + 1) $ is evenly divisible by $p$.**

**If $p$ is prime and $a$ is any whole number, then p divides evenly into $a^p - a$.**

I clearly understand Euler's proof for the first theorem and when I looked at the proof for the second theorem, I am little lost. Euler applies the first theorem in the proof of the second theorem. You can look at the proof of the second theorem [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B11G2cT1kRIfZ2p6Rkp1eG42MFU)

And I am wondering whether $a^p-a$ can be factored in to $(a+1)^p - (a^p + 1) $. If so, please tell me how to factor $a^p-a$.

THANK YOU!

Comment: The proof you have linked is just a wishy-washy and incomplete way to rewrite the proof by induction on $a$. You actually need a two-sided induction: $a \to a+1$ and $a \to a-1$ (the latter part the author forgets, but it is necessary to get all $a \in \mathbb{Z}$, not just the nonnegative $a$).

Comment: Here is a more formal writeup of the induction proof, sans the $a \to a-1$ part: https://www.artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php?title=Fermat%27s_Little_Theorem#Proof_1_.28Induction.29

Comment: @DietrichBurde This line: $(1+p)^p - (1+1) = 2^p - 2$ which resembles the first theorem.

Comment: But my ultimate question is whether we can factor $a^p - a$ or not.

Comment: You can factor it into $a(a^{p-1}-1)$, not into $(a+1)^p-(a^p+1)$.